# Change variable values with loop

Tags: r, loops

I have a problem with loops in R. I am trying to change values of a variable `sex ratio` in four integer value (0-1-2-3). The original variable `sex ratio` has :

`0-> 13; 0.33->58; 0.66->0.66; 1->19`

```
# create a new column classifying sex ratio for multinomial model 
triplets2$multi <- rep(0, dim(triplets2)[1])      
for (r in 1:dim(triplets2)[1]){  # for each row of dataframe 
    if(triplets2$sex.ratio[r]==0){ triplets2$multi[r]<-0 } 
    if(triplets2$sex.ratio[r]==0.333333333333333){ triplets2$multi[r]<-1 }
    if(triplets2$sex.ratio[r]==0.666666666666667){ triplets2$multi[r]<-2 } 
    if(triplets2$sex.ratio[r]==1){ triplets2$multi[r]<-3 }
}
```

But when I go to check if the code works properly, there is a problem of classification.
Any ideas?

Comment: please post some code and include the language in the tag

Comment: "# create a new column classifying sex ratio for multinomial model
triplets2$multi<-rep(0,dim(triplets2)[1])

# run loop 
for (r in 1:dim(triplets2)[1]){ # for each row of dataframe
  if(triplets2$sex.ratio[r]==0){
    triplets2$multi[r]<-0
  }
    if(triplets2$sex.ratio[r]==0.333333333333333){
      triplets2$multi[r]<-1
    }
  if(triplets2$sex.ratio[r]==0.666666666666667){
    triplets2$multi[r]<-2
  }
  if(triplets2$sex.ratio[r]==1){
    triplets2$multi[r]<-3
  }}"

Comment: When i go to check with function table(triplets2$multi), r told me that i have 0->150 and 3 ->19. Basically the code classified values 0, 0.33 and 0.66 in one category.

Comment: Why don't you just use `triplets2$multi<-3*triplets2$sex.ratio` ?

Comment: Thanks @etienne is a good idea but i would like to improve my ability in using loop. Anyway thanks for your tip

Comment: @DanieleBattocchio: in R, using loops is almost never the best solution. There are a lot of ways to achieve the same result in less time, less code, ... I would advise you to learn functions like `apply`, `ifelse` rather than `for` loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue, most likely, is that the values in your `sex.ratio` column are not exactly equal to 0.333333333333333 or 0.666666666666667.

You could round the values from your data frame like so:

```
# create a new column classifying sex ratio for multinomial model 
triplets2$multi <- rep(0, dim(triplets2)[1])      
for (r in 1:dim(triplets2)[1]){  # for each row of dataframe 
    if(triplets2$sex.ratio[r]==0){ triplets2$multi[r]<-0 } 
    if(round(triplets2$sex.ratio[r],2)==0.33){ triplets2$multi[r]<-1 }
    if(round(triplets2$sex.ratio[r],2)==0.67){ triplets2$multi[r]<-2 } 
    if(triplets2$sex.ratio[r]==1){ triplets2$multi[r]<-3 }
}
```

then it should work.

FYI, you should take a look at `ifelse` for operations such as this, rather than using a loop.